# Apt updating can't connect to server

Tags: apt, updates

I am trying to update Debian stretch but when making the connection to repositories it will spontaneously hang at different addresses like this:

```
Hit:1 http://repo.steampowered.com/steam precise InRelease
Hit:2 http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease                                 
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/papirus/papirus/ubuntu xenial InRelease               
Hit:4 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_11.x stretch InRelease                         
0% [Connecting to prod.debian.map.fastly.net (2a04:4e42:10::204)] [Connecting to dl.g
```

or this

```
Hit:1 http://repo.steampowered.com/steam precise InRelease
Hit:2 http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease                                 
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/papirus/papirus/ubuntu xenial InRelease               
Hit:4 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_11.x stretch InRelease                         
0% [Connecting to ftp-chi.osuosl.org (2600:3402:200:227::2)] [Connecting to prod.debi
```

I'm not sure where these repositories are listed either, as it seems commenting out lines in `/etc/apt/sources.list` does not change the problem.

Comment: "these repositories" look like redirects from deb.nodesource.com. That's the one to temporarily disable.

Comment: @user535733 where is that listed? It doesn't appear to be in my `sources.list` file.

Comment: You added it when you installed node. Where did you add it?

Comment: @user535733 I can disable it but then i get the hang after the previous listed item.

Comment: Then you seem to be having network problems. If you were running Ubuntu, we could refer you to some good help...but you're not running Ubuntu.

Comment: This site offers support only for [official flavors of Ubuntu](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/flavours). *Debian* is off-topic here but questions about it are welcome at our related site: [unix.se].

Answer (score 2):

You may also want to check the /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ directory for additional files.  If there are files in that directory, try moving them out or removing them and trying the update again.

However, it doesn't sounds like the problem is related to a source list, you may just have a poor internet connection or other networking issues.  In that case, you can try other devices or run some tests to start debugging the issue.

Comment: I can actually go into `sources.list.d` and remove all repositories and then updating checking will just hang from the start and give me this error again: `0% [Connecting to ftp-chi.osuosl.org (2600:3402:200:227::2)] [Connecting to prod.debi`

Comment: Yes, it sounds like you're having other network connection issues (or maybe DNS issues).  If you're familiar with other network troubleshooting techniques (such as ping <host>), I would start there.